# Can emberjs always properly escape string to ensure site safety?

Tags: jquery, string, ember.js, escaping

I know that one should always escape a string properly before pass a value that is in string to database or process it. However, a concern raised when i was looking at emberjs's guides, [under WRITING HELPERS inside TEMPLATES tab](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/), among this code,

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('highlight', function(value, options) {
var escaped = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(value);
return new Handlebars.SafeString('<span class="highlight">' + escaped + '</span>');
});
```

the `escapeExpression` (seems like) a default function for emberjs and emberjs is a client side script framwork, which means one can easily modify the mechanism how it work, so that escapeExpression will means nothing! Is that true? If thats not the case, why? I keep ask myself how can a client site framwork ever escape string safely if it actually can be modified by the clients themselves?
It's bothering me so much.

Comment: If a client would manipulate it, it would only affect him self and no other user.

Comment: @Prinzhorn But what if the function he adjusted, like escapeExpression, actually validate the value to pass into a database?

Comment: How is your database related to a client side application? Of course you are escaping values on your server as well, but that's a different story.

Comment: that's why you never rely on any client side checks and do them again on your server side

Comment: @Prinzhorn Seem emberjs use controller of its own to validate or pass values and therefore, communicate with database through a server side language. But enable non-escaped string talk to controller, means, its safety is compromised in client side already...hum...so I guess emberjs's security mechanism of escapeExpress is just....for general user who is not hacker?

Comment: @Circadian So we should create another MVC server side framework, beside client side MVC, correct?